# How to call function from itself and call it again from outside

Tags: php, function

Basically I have a function with an if condition (inside it) that if is true, it would call the function again. After that, the function is called again but from outside.

This is a minimal version of the function to explain the problem:

```
function products($arg) {
         // do stuff here
         if($some_variable == '1') {
            products('arg-2');
         }
}

products('arg-1');
products('arg-3');
```

The first instance of the function `products('arg-1')` runs successfully.

The second instance `products('arg-2')` runs successfully.

The third instance `products('arg-3')` won't run for some reason after the second instance (called from inside the function) is called. If I don't call the function from itself, the third instance and any further ones will continue running as expected.

So, in summary, it seems like calling the function from itself stops any further calls of the function. Is there a solution for this behavior?

Comment: Why dont you use a loop?

Comment: I am not sure what `// do stuff here` does but it is possible that you are either running into infinite recursion when calling `products('arg-1')` or the `// do stuff here` logic does nothing with `products('arg-3')`

Comment: Where is `$some_variable` set? Fix that and the arguments and it works.. https://3v4l.org/mLIJ2

Comment: This may be a minimal version of the function to explain the problem, but I don't think it's a [mcve].

Comment: https://3v4l.org/I08Gb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is very likely something wrong with the logic inside of your function because this simple recursion example works fine.

```
<?php
function recursive( $arg )
{
    echo $arg;

    if( $arg === 1 )
    {
        recursive( 2 );
    }
}

recursive( 1 );
recursive( 3 );
```

produces

```
123
```

Comment: You are right, there was something wrong with the logic inside the function. Thanks!